# Проблемы с запуском apache-kafka после перезагрузки сервера

Tags: ubuntu, apache-kafka

Добрый день! Я выставил приоритет загрузки сервисов на одном из серверов. Все сервисы стартуют корректно, за исключением кафки, которая стартует последней. Скидываю лог кафки после запуска сервера.

```
(kafka.server.KafkaConfig)
[2016-11-10 13:15:58,150] INFO starting (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2016-11-10 13:15:58,157] INFO Connecting to zookeeper on k3-one:2181
(kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2016-11-10 13:16:04,593] FATAL Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 6000
at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:1232)
at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:156)
at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:130)
at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.createZkClientAndConnection(ZkUtils.scala:75)
at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.apply(ZkUtils.scala:57)
at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZk(KafkaServer.scala:294)
at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:180)
at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:37)
at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:67)
at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2016-11-10 13:16:04,595] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2016-11-10 13:16:04,599] INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2016-11-10 13:16:04,600] FATAL Fatal error during KafkaServerStartable startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 6000
at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:1232)
at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:156)
at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:130)
at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.createZkClientAndConnection(ZkUtils.scala:75)
at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.apply(ZkUtils.scala:57)
at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZk(KafkaServer.scala:294)
at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:180)
at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:37)
at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:67)
at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2016-11-10 13:16:04,601] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

Так вот, если же я вручную останавливаю сервис и запускаю, то запуск проходит без каких либо проблем. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть косяк? Заранее благодарен за уделенное моему вопросу время!

Comment: Ваш кафка не видит zookeeper on k3-one:2181. Вероятно, к этому моменту еще не запустился сетевой интерфейс. Надо или выставить зависимость от сети, или увеличить таймаут.

Comment: Что в таком случае порекомендуете делать?

Comment: Уточните версию своего сервера и способ запуска служб.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
init.d
запуск сервисов происходит автоматически, в таком порядке: postgresql > redis > zookeeper > cassandra > glassfish > kafka (host1) |
postgresql > rabbitmq > redis > apache-storm > glassfish (host2)

Comment: покажите кофиг кафки в ini.d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, Вам поможет добавление третьей строки в init скрипт кафки:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          kafka
# Required-Start:    $network $syslog $named
....
```

Comment: Благодарю вас! Так же поменял приоритет. Поставил на 9-й поток. Все здорово, еще раз спасибо!